# How can I get the http body when python3 throws a HTTPError

Tags: http, exception, python-3.x, urllib

How can I get the `http` body when python3.2 throws a `HTTPError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\RileyRen\Desktop\query_token.py", line 17, in <module>
    File "D:\Environment\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 495, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

python throws an `HTTPError`,But I can't get the http body.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Catch it and use it as if it were a response:

```
try:
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(...)
    # ...
except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
    data = error.read()
    # data contains the content
```

Answer (score 2):

just like the normal process.

```
err.read()
```